# Counting occurrences of value in SQL

Tags: sql, count, group-by

Lets say we have a table nobel(yr, subject, winner).

I want to get a result which will return year, column of number of chemistry awards in that year, column of number of physics awards in that year.

How would you do that?

```
SELECT yr, count(subject='Physics'), count(subject='Chemistry') FROM nobel GROUP BY yr
```

does not work.

Comment: what are you getting when you execute the query?

Comment: Two columns of total number of awards in that year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query does not work because the conditional returns a value of 0 or 1, and `count` counts non-NULL values.

Try using `sum` instead of `count`:

```
SELECT yr, sum(subject='Physics'), sum(subject='Chemistry')
FROM nobel
GROUP BY yr
```

By the way, not all databases treat conditional expressions as integers.  The standard syntax would be:

```
select yr, sum(case when subject = 'Physics' then 1 else 0 end) as NumPhysics,
       sum(case when subject = 'Chemistry' then 1 else 0 end) as NumChemistry
from nobel
group by yr
```

You can also get the same information on multiple rows by doing:

```
select yr, subject, count(*)
from Nobel
where subject in ('Physics', 'Chemistry')
group by yr, subject
```

Answer (score 1):

Won't this work?

```
select yr, subject, count(*) awards
from nobel
where subject in ('physics', 'chemistry')
group by yr, subject
```

Comment: It would, but it is not what I wanted, perhaps I did not phrase my question right, I wanted a column of number of chemistry awards in that year and a column of number of physics awards in that year